Dual power supply setup on prebuilt
I have a low end pre-built pc from Fujitsu that I want to turn into a media server with an external graphics card for transcoding. To do so i bought another power supply and a magic card (I can't find a better way to name it. A dual psu syncer to plug between both psu). As the pre-built does not have a molex, I bought a sata -> molex converter.
When turning on the pc, the external power supply does not seem to turn on (or at least, the fan does not start even for a split second). Is there some option to activate in the bios ? Does it need a system to power up ? Or maybe it just waits for load ?
I need this setup as, since it's a low end pre-built, it uses a proprietary psu format/a format I could not find any information about online. It only has 8 pins from the psu going straight into the motherboard. Then 2 4 pins headers to plug sata to, so nothing to plug into my graphics card. The 180W psu would probably lack the power for the GPU I have.
I can provide photos if needed.
Have a great day

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

What is a magic card? How do you think you are signalling the new PS to start? Why are you trying this in a "dual" setup? Please clarify your question, adding details, and explaining why you made the decisions you have made so far. Add this info to the question itself to improve and clarify it. Do not add info down here in comments.

Your question is unclear - especially, as others have stated talking about this "magic card" and when the media server needs to be on.  In order to start a PSU you need to short 2 pins on it (ie the PS_ON sensor needs to be grounded) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS-ON_Signal

Thanks for your feedbacks about the question, i've tried improving it with a link to the "magic card" and some more explanation about why doing that.

Your question is still unclear.  How many PC's are you powering up (I'd assume 1, but you talk about "both PC") ?  What model and How is your external graphics card powered and how big is the second PSU?   Why don't you just use the more powerful PSU and drop the 180w one altogether?   What happens if you short the appropriate pins on the second PSU?   (One thing I can say - this is almost certainly not a BIOS thing)

I posit the way that "magic card" is meant to work is that when it sees voltage across the Molex connector it is meant to briefly short the appropriate pins for the second PSU to turn it on.   It looks like that is not happening.  I wonder if the relay on the "magic card" is faulty.    Do you have LED1 and LED2 soldered on the magic board, and do they come on?

Sorry, i meant both PSU. The "magic card" could be faulty, but I tried the other one in the pack (often sold by pairs) and it does not seem to work either. I'll try further tests today with some load on the graphics card to see if it works or not. As for replacing the first PSU, I can't because, as i said, the pre-built psu is a proprietary format.
